# How can I make this scrollviewer in the grid cell work both horizontaly and verticaly?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, scrollviewer

I have a grid with some data and one of the cells contains rather long strings (and there could be quite a few). So to not use too much of the available window space, I'd like those strings to be scrollable. Vertically works, but whatever I try, I can't get a horizontal scrollbar.

This is my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"           
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="250">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>    
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>           
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BoundTexts}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and here's the code behind to test.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows; 

namespace WpfApp1

{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<BoundClass> temp = new List<BoundClass>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                string t = ""; // just to create some long strings.
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) // I know it can be done better.
                {
                    t += $"{j*10:D2}********";
                }               
                temp.Add(new BoundClass(t));
            }
            BoundTexts = temp.ToArray();
            DataContext = this;
        }       

        public BoundClass[] BoundTexts { get; set; }
    } 

    public class BoundClass
    {
        public string Text { get; set;}
        public BoundClass(string text)
        {
            Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

I know there are a few similar questions on here, but as far as I have seen, they are all shrouded in templates and other complex topics. Also some are answered by "make sure you have a restraining container around it", I think I do by the grid.

Comment: Why don't you use a ListBox? It already has a working ScrollViewer and provides virtualization to significantly improve the performance. However, you must constraint the Height of the ItemsControl. Otherwise it will stretch to show all items.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The proper way to add a `ScrollViewer` to an `ItemsControl` is to put it into the `ControlTemplate` to wrap the `ItemsPresenter`. This way the `ScrollViewer` behaves correctly.

If you don't do it this way (and instead wrap the `ItemsControl`) the `ScrollViewer` will try to scroll the `ItemsControl` and not the items!
But you want the `ScrollViewer` to detect when items of the `ItemsControl` overflow. Naturally, the `ItemsControl` itself will stretch to occupy the available space - it won't overflow and will be displayed correctly (fully visible). But the items do overflow the space of the `ItemsControl`. That's why wrapping the `ItemsControl` won't work as expected.

Additionally, you must explicitly enable the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`. It's important to know that setting it to `Auto` will impact the performance. It's recommended to set it to `Hidden` or `Visible`.

```xml
<ItemsControl Height="200">
  <ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
      <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ItemsPresenter />
      </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.Template>

  <!-- Consider to enable virtualization by adding a VirtualizingStackPanel as host Panel.
       Important: don't forget to set ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to 'True' -->
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `"Auto"` should do the trick.

Default value for `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` is `ScrollBarVisibility.Visible` **BUT** for `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` is **`ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled`**. So it should be even enough to set only `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = "Auto"`

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```